# TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of null when running react-native application on android

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native application that runs fine on iOS, however when I try and run on Android I get the following error.

```
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of null, js engine: hermes
     ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
          This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
     ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
          This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

Googling these errors I get advice to delete node modules or run react-native-clean-project which I have tried with no result. Is there some way to get more specific information about these errors? The Application is quite large so I am not sure where the TypeError is occurring exactly

Comment: I have exactly the same error. Can you edit your question and append your package.json? Maybe there is a problem with one dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use i18next? For me it was the i18next configuration. The detect method looked something like this.

```js
i18next
    .use({
        type:              'languageDetector',
        init:              () => {
        },
        cacheUserLanguage: () => {
        },
        detect:            () => {
            const { SettingsManager, I18nManager } = NativeModules;
            const { settings }                     = SettingsManager;
            let locale;

            if (PlatformHelper.isIOS()) {
                locale = settings.AppleLocale || settings.AppleLanguages[0];
            } else {
                locale = I18nManager.localeIdentifier;
            }

            if (_.isEmpty(locale)) {
                locale = 'en';
            }

            return locale.split('_')[0];
        },
    })
```

SettingsManager is null under ios. So we had to move `const { settings } = SettingsManager;` inside the `PlatformHelper.isIOS()` block.

```js
detect:            () => {
    const { SettingsManager, I18nManager } = NativeModules;
    let locale;

    if (PlatformHelper.isIOS()) {
        const { settings } = SettingsManager;
        locale             = settings.AppleLocale || settings.AppleLanguages[0];
    } else {
        locale = I18nManager.localeIdentifier;
    }

    if (_.isEmpty(locale)) {
        locale = 'en';
    }

    return locale.split('_')[0];
},
```